# JIRA API after POST returns { errorMessages: [ 'Internal server error' ], errors: {} }

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a new issue utilizing the JIRA REST API and whenever I try, I get back the following generic error:
`{ errorMessages: [ 'Internal server error' ], errors: {} }`

I can successfully GET from the API, and the credentials I'm connecting with have full Admin access to JIRA (so it's not an Auth issue), but I get this error every time with POST. Below is a snippet of the JSON data I'm sending. Am I missing anything obvious?

Below is my JavaScript code. Note I'm using `jira-connector` from npm. (Real domain replaced with mydomain for this sample code)

```
const JiraClient = require('jira-connector');

const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

function createNewIssue(fields) {
const encoded = process.env.JIRA_ENCODED_PW;

const jira = new JiraClient({
    host: 'mydomain.atlassian.net',
    basic_auth: {
        base64: encoded
    }
});

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jira.issue.createIssue(fields, (error, issue) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log(issue);
            resolve(encoded);
        }
    });
})
}
```

Below is the JSON that's being passed into `fields` in the JS above. Note `customfield_17300` is a radio button, and `customfield_17300` is a multi-select box. For both cases, I've tried using the "id" and also the actual string "name" value. All IDs below were taken straight from a API GET of the same issue in question:

```
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "id": "13400"
    },
    "summary": "TEST API TICKET -  01",

    "issuetype": {
  "id": "11701"
},

    "customfield_14804": { "id": "13716" },

    "customfield_14607": "Hardware",

    "customfield_17300": [
  {
    "id": "18322"
  }
] ,

    "customfield_16301": "Customer PO",

    "customfield_14800": "LA, California",

    "customfield_16302": "FEDEX 234982347g"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sigh* I figured it out... other posts that said this cryptic error was due to a malformed JSON were correct.

In my route, I passed `fields` as coming from `req.body.fields` which actually dove into the `fields` values instead of passing it straight through. This made it so that when the JSON was sent to JIRA the `fields` outer wrapper was missing. I changed my route to pass along `req.body` instead of `req.body.fields` and all was well.

...that was a fun 4 hours...

Comment: To add, I had different troubles with worklogs, but not comments.  I remember I wanted to try our UI's date style of "22/Nov/17 02:54 PM", but that didn't work, and had to resort to their ISO-8601 but still modified format from what my GNU date utility provides.  I had to remove the colon from the TZ, and make sure nanoseconds was present.  I also removed quotes from around the `timeSpentSeconds` number value.